# How to sort sheet by groups of three rows without changing internal arrangement of groups

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, microsoft-excel-2011

I created an Excel file showing a list of golfers and their scores on 18 holes.

[image]

I want to sort by the Net Total, while preserving the rest of the formatting.  When I try to sort the usual way, I get all the Net totals at the top, and the names and Gross and Net scores somewhere else.  How can I sort by the total, keeping the 3 rows per individual in tact? (The three rows are:  Name&Hole number, Gross score, Net score.)  This third row per person has the total at the end.  I want to sort by this column.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You can upload your screen shot somewhere and post a link to it here. I or someone else will gladly edit the image into your post for you.

Comment: Thank you!  Here is a link to the document I'm trying to sort.https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67093089/Sorting%20experiment.xlsx

Comment: Can you please link to a screenshot instead? Not everybody who could help you is going to be willing to download a workbook and open it (security concerns and time constraints).

Comment: see below for link to a screenshot

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67093089/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-09%20at%209.59.17%20PM.png

Comment: If I'm to use multiple sort criteria, I would first Sort By column T (Total Net score) but can someone tell me what would the next Sort By(s) be in order to get the result I'm looking for?  Maybe it isn't possible, and the  spreadsheet needs to be redesigned?  It's important to maintain the Gross & Net rows under each name, maintaining the three lines per person, while sorting them in order by Total net score.

Comment: So you want to sort the people and their data (all 3 rows together) by total score? Is the issue keeping the sets of 3 rows together when you do this?

Comment: Yes, exactly!  Can you figure out how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with three helper columns.

In `U2:U5` enter `=A2` in each cell (don't just fill down -- you want the same value/name in each cell).

In `V2:V5` enter `=T4` in each cell (again, don't fill down).

In `W2:W5` enter `=MOD(ROW()-2,4)+1`. You can fill this one down through `W5`.

Once all these values are entered, select `U2:W5` and fill down to the first blank row beneath the last record on the sheet.

After doing this, select your sheet from `A1` to the last cell with data in  column `W`. Now, sort the data (Data ribbon > Sort) with the following criteria:

1. Column V, Values, Smallest to Largest
2. Column U, Values, A to Z
3. Column W, Values, Smallest to Largest

That should allow you to sort the data as you wish. And if you no longer need to sort the data, you can simply delete these helper columns.

Comment: Oh, my!  This worked!  It's beautiful. I need to do some research on what the =MOD(ROW) -2,4)+1 means.  I enabled me to save the formatting with the spaces between the people, and it would be easy to either delete or hide the 3 helper columns after each sort.  Thank you SO much!

Comment: `MOD(x,4)` returns the remainder of x when divided by 4. `ROW()-2` is the current row number minus 2. This was just a way of getting the formula to repeat 1,2,3,4 when filled down. Now that I think about it, it wasn't really necessary -- filling 1,2,3,4,5,... all the way down would have worked the same.

Comment: Glad to help! If you could, please click the check mark to the left of this answer to mark your question as being resolved by this answer. This lets other people that come to this question with a similar problem see that there is a working solution.